# What am I doing wrong with this function?

Tags: jquery

```
"fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            var sReportType = (jQuery('#report_type').val() == "") ? "Downline" : jQuery('#report_type').val();
            var aRankID = (jQuery('#rank_id').val() == null) ? [] : jQuery('#rank_id').val();

            aoData.push({
                "name": "report_type",
                "value": sReportType,
                "name": "rankid",
                "value": aRankID.join(',')
            });
        },
```

aRankID should either be an empty array or populated with the values from a multi select box.

When I first load the page here is what firebug returns.

```
>>> jQuery('#rank_id').val();
null
```

After I make some selections here is what it returns.

```
>>> jQuery('#rank_id').val();
["1", "2", "3"]
```

I must be missing something because it is causing my ajax page to crash.  And I need to use.join because my ajax page is expecting a string.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
        aoData.push({
            "name": "report_type",
            "value": jQuery('#report_type').val() || "Downline",
            "name": "rankid",
            "value": (jQuery('#rank_id').val() || []).join(",")
        });
  }
```

Comment: If there is a better way please let me know.  I'm only as good as you guys point out my flaws. :)

Comment: This didn't fix it as well.  What I need to do is pass rankid as "" if jQuery('#rank_id').val() = "" or null which ever it is supposed to be when empty.

Comment: @JamesWilson Do you want `"value":jQuery('#rank_id').val()`? I have comprehended that from your last comment. ----- In my answer , I just interpretted your question's code to shorter code. That was all.

Comment: No because that will pass an array [1,2,3].  I need it to pass "1,2,3" or "".  That might work, I will just have to rewrite the classic asp code to look for an array rather than a string.

Comment: @JamesWilson `jQuery('#rank_id').val()` can't be an `Array`, is it so ?!!

Comment: Well ok, I assume it is an array.  When I use firebug to return the results with jQuery('#rank_id').val(); this is what it sends to the console.  >>> jQuery('#rank_id').val();
["1", "3", "4"]

Comment: @JamesWilson how many DOM elements with the id `rank_id` have you got on the page ?

Comment: Just one.  I think I have figured out the issue.  aoData.push({
seems to only want to add one key/value set at a time.  Testing this theory.

Comment: @ManseUK Probably `#rank_id` is `select` element with `multiple` attribute.

Comment: That is what it was.  I had to add a seperate aoData.push for each key/value pair I want to send.  Sorry for the trouble!  It is working as needed now. :)

Comment: I just did.  It works as well. :)  Now I need to figure out why this is taking 20 seconds. =\  That'll be fun.

Answer (score 2):

Should

```
var aRankID = (jQuery('#rank_id').val() == null) ? [] : jQuery('#report_type').val();
```

not be

```
var aRankID = (jQuery('#rank_id').val() == null) ? [] : jQuery('#rank_id').val();
```

You are using `jQuery('#report_type').val()` instead of `jQuery('#rank_id').val()`

Comment: My bad!  I copied a previous working example and forgot to change that instance!  Thank you both!

Comment: @JamesWilson some times all you need is a second pair of eyes :-)

Comment: Well that fixed a likely issue.  But it did not fix the intended issue.  After making that change it still crashes the Ajax page.  here is what is sent. mDataProp_6 6
rankid 
sColumns 
sEcho 1

Comment: Not sure how to format it well inside a comment.  But basically something is wrong with the code above. =(

Comment: Can you update your question and include the HTMl that shows `#rank_id` it sounds like you have more than one on the page which is why its returning an array

Answer (score 1):

This looks fishy:

```
var aRankID = (jQuery('#rank_id').val() == null) ? [] : jQuery('#report_type').val();
```

Did you mean to check `#rank_id` but use the value from `#report_type`?

Comment: My bad!  I copied a previous working example and forgot to change that instance!  Thank you both!